# Errors while trying to install Chrome using terminal

Tags: google-chrome, installation, terminal

I want to use Selenium to scrape some data and I am working in AWS EC2. In order to run Selenium Webdriver with Python on an AWS EC2 Instance, I have to install chrome. So, I tried to run this command in terminal to install chrome:

`curl https://intoli.com/install-google-chrome.sh | bash`

Then what I am getting is:

```
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
100  9526  100  9526    0     0   930k      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--  930k
Working in /tmp/google-chrome-installation
/tmp/google-chrome-installation /tmp
Configuring the Google Chrome repo in /etc/yum.repos.d/google-chrome.repo
bash: line 17: /etc/yum.repos.d/google-chrome.repo: No such file or directory
bash: line 18: /etc/yum.repos.d/google-chrome.repo: No such file or directory
bash: line 19: /etc/yum.repos.d/google-chrome.repo: No such file or directory
bash: line 20: /etc/yum.repos.d/google-chrome.repo: No such file or directory
bash: line 21: /etc/yum.repos.d/google-chrome.repo: No such file or directory
bash: line 22: /etc/yum.repos.d/google-chrome.repo: No such file or directory
bash: line 26: yum: command not found
--2023-02-06 06:53:47--  https://dl.google.com/linux/linux_signing_key.pub
Resolving dl.google.com (dl.google.com)... 172.253.63.190, 172.253.63.91, 172.253.63.136, ...
Connecting to dl.google.com (dl.google.com)|172.253.63.190|:443... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 200 OK
Length: 12415 (12K) [application/octet-stream]
Saving to: ‘linux_signing_key.pub’

linux_signing_key.pub             100%[=============================================================>]  12.12K  --.-KB/s    in 0s

2023-02-06 06:53:47 (95.4 MB/s) - ‘linux_signing_key.pub’ saved [12415/12415]

bash: line 28: rpm: command not found
Attempting a direction installation with yum.
bash: line 40: yum: command not found
bash: line 54: yum: command not found
Downloading the Google Chrome RPM file.
bash: line 59: yum: command not found
bash: line 63: yumdownloader: command not found
--2023-02-06 06:53:47--  https://dl.google.com/linux/direct/google-chrome-stable_current_x86_64.rpm
Resolving dl.google.com (dl.google.com)... 172.253.63.190, 172.253.63.91, 172.253.63.136, ...
Connecting to dl.google.com (dl.google.com)|172.253.63.190|:443... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 200 OK
Length: 98165972 (94M) [application/x-rpm]
Saving to: ‘google-chrome-stable_current_x86_64.rpm’

google-chrome-stable_current_x86_ 100%[=============================================================>]  93.62M   418MB/s    in 0.2s

2023-02-06 06:53:47 (418 MB/s) - ‘google-chrome-stable_current_x86_64.rpm’ saved [98165972/98165972]

Downloaded google-chrome-stable_current_x86_64.rpm
bash: line 70: rpm: command not found
Installing the required font dependencies.
bash: line 76: yum: command not found
main: line 100: repoquery: command not found
http://: Invalid host name.
Extracting glibc...
main: line 107: rpm2cpio: command not found
main: line 100: repoquery: command not found
http://: Invalid host name.
Extracting util-linux...
main: line 107: rpm2cpio: command not found
main: line 100: repoquery: command not found
http://: Invalid host name.
Extracting libmount...
main: line 107: rpm2cpio: command not found
main: line 100: repoquery: command not found
http://: Invalid host name.
Extracting libblkid...
main: line 107: rpm2cpio: command not found
main: line 100: repoquery: command not found
http://: Invalid host name.
Extracting libuuid...
main: line 107: rpm2cpio: command not found
main: line 100: repoquery: command not found
http://: Invalid host name.
Extracting libselinux...
main: line 107: rpm2cpio: command not found
main: line 100: repoquery: command not found
http://: Invalid host name.
Extracting pcre...
main: line 107: rpm2cpio: command not found
Finding dependency for ldd.sh
main: line 176: repoquery: command not found
Finding dependency for ldd.sh
main: line 176: repoquery: command not found
Finding dependency for ldd.sh
main: line 176: repoquery: command not found
Finding dependency for ldd.sh
main: line 176: repoquery: command not found
Finding dependency for ldd.sh
main: line 176: repoquery: command not found
Finding dependency for ldd.sh
main: line 176: repoquery: command not found
Finding dependency for ldd.sh
main: line 176: repoquery: command not found
```

And these last 2 lines are repeating infinitely.

What should I do to move on?